# I don't understand Application Domains

Tags: .net, appdomain

.NET has this concept of Application Domains which from what I understand can be used to load an assembly into memory. I've done some research on Application Domains as well as go to my local book store for some additional knowledge on this subject matter but it seems very scarce.

All I know that I can do with Application Domains is to load assemblies in memory and I can unload them when I want.

**What are the capabilities other that I have mentioned of Application Domains? Do Threads respect Application Domains boundaries? Are there any drawbacks from loading Assemblies in different Application Domains other than the main Application Domains beyond performance of communication?**

Links to resources that discuss Application Domains would be nice as well. I've already checked out MSDN which doesn't have that much information about them.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

AppDomains best visualized as a very light weight process.

There can be N AppDomains per .Net Process but generally speaking there is only one.  The real advantage of AppDomains is they provide an isolation boundary within your process.  Objects can only talk to each other across an AppDomain boundary via remoting or serialization.

It's also possible to run 2 AppDomains at completely different security levels within a process.  This can allow you to run your main application at Full Trust while running Untrusted Plugins at a much lower trust level.

It's hard to blanket say yes or no to whether or not a thread respects an AppDomain.  It's possible for a single thread to be in N different AppDomains.  Such a situation is possible if an object in one AppDomain makes a remote call to an object in another AppDomain.  The thread will have to transition between the AppDomains in order to complete.

The disadvantage of AppDomains is mainly complexity.  Remoting can take a little bit of time to get your head around and properly setting up an AppDomain can be a non-trivial process.

You may want to take a peek through the MSDN documentation on AppDomains.  It's hard to find a succint tutorial that describes them because they have a variety of complex features.  This provides a nice overview which if it doesn't answer your question directly will at least point you in the right place.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxk374d9.aspx

This document is no longer maintained please refer to this for the updated version:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Main concern is that I don't understand the capabilties I'm getting by using them. I read that they are a lightweight process but they seem that the carry more than just that and I may be missing something that could bite me later on. IE I'm taking out more than I need.

Answer (score 93):

JaredPar's answer is good, except he doesn't note the [raison d'etre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raison_d'%C3%AAtre) for AppDomains - which is that you can only UNLOAD an Assembly by unloading its AppDomain.  If you are a long-running OS process, and you expect to have to load *and then  later unload* assemblies for whatever reason then you need an AppDomain.  The prototypical example here is ASP.NET, which loads app code assemblies on demand and then can unload them later, when the apps are no longer being actively used.

The cost you pay for the ability to unload is that independence - you need to communicate across the AppDomain boundary,  Can't make a simple method call.  You need to manage the AppDomain lifecycle. Etc.

If you just need to dynamically load Assemblies and don't think you'll need to unload them *during the life of a single process* then you probably *don't* need to run multiple AppDomains.  A good example here might be a rich app that supports a plug-in model, where it sniffs out plug-in assemblies in a "etc" directory and loads 'em all up.  However, if the plug-in model calls for unloading the plug-ins ... well.

There are outlyer scenarios.  Like, suppose you want to load 2 different versions of an Assembly at the same time.  You can run into pitfalls if you don't segregate them with AppDomains. But that will be fairly rare.

The core scenario that justifies the existence of AppDomains is the long running process that must be able to unload assemblies.

Of course, applications could rely on the OS process when you want to unload an assembly.  In other words, you could have 3 or 4 cooperating processes running, each with its own set of Assemblies, and when you want to unload an assembly, just shut down the process that hosts that assembly.  But the AppDomain offers a higher-perf mechanism to do that, without requiring process stop/start or cross-process comms, which is heavier still than the cross-AppDomain comms described previously.  I mean it's still remoting but it is slower and more context switching.

Comment: Because it's fun to use French words in answers to computer science questions.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft and it helps educate people who may not be familiar with what is a commonly used foreign term which perfectly encapsulates an idea which is much more clumsily defined in English.

Comment: @SamHolder The linked Wikipedia article says the English translation is "reason for existence". That doesn't seem too clumsily defined to me.

Comment: For my money this is the best answer, because the "raison d'etre" is not clearly stated anywhere on MSDN, as far as I can find.

Answer (score 27):

Some things you can do with AppDomains:

- you can shut it down without endangering the stability of your program.
- You can load code and give this less privileges then your own process (e.g. your process runs fully trusted but you load code in a separate AppDomain that cannot even create a file on the disk.)
- You can handle unhandled exceptions of a AppDomain without having to crash your process.
- Etc.

Simply put, it's a security boundary and allmost a process boundary. As far as performance goes, multiple AppDomains within a process does not represent significant overhead. Launching a separate process instead of an AppDomain is far more costly.