# what is the difference between AppDomain.CreateInstance and Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, activator

I want to ask a question to realize the difference between AppDomain and Activator, I loaded my dll via appdomain.CreateInstance. But I realized that more method to create instance. Therefore when or where do I choose this method?
Example1:

```
    // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current
    // application domain.
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
    // Get the type to use.
    Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
    // Get the method to call.
    MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
    // Create an instance.
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    // Execute the method.
    myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
```

Example2:

```
public WsdlClassParser CreateWsdlClassParser()
{
    this.CreateAppDomain(null);

    string AssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; 
    WsdlClassParser parser = null;
    try
    {                
        parser = (WsdlClassParser) this.LocalAppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(AssemblyPath,
                                          typeof(Westwind.WebServices.WsdlClassParser).FullName).Unwrap() ;                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }                        
    return parser;
}
```

Example3:

```
private static void InstantiateMyTypeSucceed(AppDomain domain)
{
    try
    {
        string asmname = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName;
        domain.CreateInstance(asmname, "MyType");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Can you explain why do I need more methods or what are the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From sscli2.0 source code, it looks like the "CreateInstance" method calls in [**AppDomain**](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid3EA6C4A680148997A79A54E888193069D32F7F85.aspx) class always delegates the call to [**Activator**](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid21405C662ECB4175BA1EEAE3112FA168427D34D3.aspx).

The sole purpose of the (almost static) **Activator** class is to "Create" instances of various classes, while **AppDomain** is introduced for quite different (and perhaps more ambitious) purposes, e.g.:

1. A light-weight unit of application isolation;
2. Optimize memory consumption because AppDomains can be Unloaded.
3. ...

The 1st and the 3rd example are straightforward, just as zmbq noted. I guess your 2nd example is from this **[post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/19/Assembly-Loading-across-AppDomains)**, where the author showed how to unload an out-of-date proxy using AppDomain.

Answer (score 2):

The first one creates an instance of type `Example` from the assembly 'example', and calls `MethodA` on it.

The third one creates an instance of `MyType` in a different [`AppDomain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094478/what-is-a-net-application-domain)

I'm not sure about the second, I don't know what `this` is, but it *seems* to create a class in the current app-domain - that is, it's similar to the first.