# Running code in a separate process

Tags: c#, process, .net-4.5

I would like to know how can I set an operation (method, block of code, etc.) to run on a different PROCESS (not thread) in a way that if the main process crash the others will still be running. Un-monitorable, but running.

I was thinking I could "compile" the block of code in a different app and then execute the result, but that wouldn't be too elegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: .NET App Domains are there for exactly this reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094478/what-is-a-net-application-domain

Comment: Not if the code is likely to throw a SOE from a 3rd party library. In which case AppDomain does not help - the entire process is killed. Whereas having the auxiliary process killed is not as bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you run a separate exe the way ms intends is to create a new appdomain and run the other code in there.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem. It's a half measure that doesn't really resolve issues with crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is use the same app/exe and pass command line parameters to signify what to run in the second instance.