# How does memory usage, cpu time, data out, and file system storage apply to my website?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Pardon my ignorance but I have a few questions that I can not seem to get the answers by searching here or google. These questions will seem completely dumb but I honestly need help with them.

On my Azure website portal I have a few things I am curious of.

How does CPU-Time apply to my website? I am unaware how I am using CPU unless this applies to hosting some type of application? I am using this "site" as a form to submit data to my database.

What exactly does "data out" mean? I am allowed 165mb per day.

What exactly is file system storage? Is this the actual space available on my Azure server to store my project and any other things I might directly host on it?

Last question is, how does memory usage apply in this scenario as well? I am allowed 1024mb per hour.

I know what CPU-Time is in desktop computing as well as memory usage but I am not exactly sure how this applies to my website. I do not know how I will be able to project if I will go over any of these limits so that I can upgrade my site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How does CPU-Time apply to my website? I am unaware how I am using CPU
>   unless this applies to hosting some type of application? I am using
>   this "site" as a form to submit data to my database.

This is CPU time used by your code. If you use a WebSite project (in ASP.NET) you may want to do PreCompilation for your WebSite proejct before deploying to Azure Website ([read about PreCompilations here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-vb)). Compiling your code is one side of the things. Rest is executing your code. Each web request that goes to a server handler/mapper/controller/aspx page/etc. uses some CPU time. Especially writing to database and so on. All these actions count toward CPU time.

But how exactly the CPU time is measured, it is not documented.

> What exactly does "data out" mean? I am allowed 165mb per day.

Every single HTTP request to your site generates a response. All the data that goes out from your website is counted as "data out". Basically all and any data that goes out of the Data Center where your WebSite is located counts as data out. This also includes any outgoing HTTP/Web Request your code might be performing against remote sources. This also is the Data that goes out if you are using `Azure SQL Database` that **is not** in the same Data Center as your WebSite.

> What exactly is file system storage? Is this the actual space
>   available on my Azure server to store my project and any other things
>   I might directly host on it?

Exactly - your project + anything you upload to it (if you allow for example file uploads) + server logs.

> Last question is, how does memory usage apply in this scenario as
>   well? I am allowed 1024mb per hour.

Memory is same as CPU cycles. However my guess is that this is much easier to gauge. Your application lives in its own .NET App Domain (check [this SO question on AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094478/what-is-a-net-application-domain)). It is relatively easy to measure memory usage for the App Domain.

Comment: Also there is a good reference on the web that I just found.
http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/windows-azure-web-sites-quotas-scaling-and-pricing/

Comment: _"Especially writing to database "_ Actually that's not CPU but I/O.

Comment: will agree that most of DB operations are I/O, but opening the connection consumes CPU on the client side, no? So we cannot exlude this from the CPU metering of the Azure Web apps platform.

Comment: @astaykov, in system storage i can store only project file? Not some data? Tables,files for work,for example? I mean, my project store data in table, is this table store at this system storage, or i should use SQL or other Storage?