# Azure Web App plans

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have just started exploring `Azure`, and my main purpose is to host the `O365 SharePoint Provider Hosted App`. Which means I need to create web sites.

I am looking at the pricing of Azure WebApp at [How Azure pricing works](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/), and they are `Free`, `Shared`, `Basic`, `Standard`, `Premium`.

There are few things which I have not understood completely.

- *Basic, Standard, and Premium plans provide Virtual Machines dedicated to your plan*: Does this mean that I will get a VM which accessible and on that my website will be hosted?
- *The Shared and Free are have cores 240 cpu minutes/per day and 60 cpu minutes/per day resectively*: What does this exactly means?
- *Azure is already on secure port i.e. `https://`* : So do I need to have an SSL for my Provider Hosted website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Service VMs are not accessible in the sense of RDP/SSH.  It just means it's not shared with other tenants.

MS has not published exactly how CPU Minutes are calculated (that I am aware of), but obviously it correlates to how heavily your app is used. [1]

The Azure *Portal* is already on https.  For web apps, MS provides a wildcard SSL cert for the *.azurewebsites.net domain.  If you use a custom domain then you are responsible for obtaining the SSL cert. [2]

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/15758256/310446
[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#bkmk_azurewebsites