# How to securely embed the F# compiler in a asp.net web app

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-compiler-services

I am developing a asp.net web app enabling users to submit F# code, which should be dynamically compiled and executed on the server. I was thinking of either hosting the F# compiler in the web app using the approach shown here:
https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/compiler.html
Or use F# interactive: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html

The idea would be to dynamically compile the F# code and then load it as an assembly in c# or have F# interactive interpret the code. However, my main concern is security and how to stop the end user from executing arbitrary code. Is there an easy way to restrict this? Thanks!

Comment: For small snippets, perhaps check out the implementation of the @FsiBot Twitter bot (https://github.com/mathias-brandewinder/fsibot).

Comment: Also, there's quite of a lot of discussion on doing this with C#. Different compiler, but many of the issues (such as security) are the same

Comment: Well the most important issue is security. What stops the user from wiping out the whole disk with a script?

Comment: One solution could be to dynamically compile the F# code using compiler services and then load the resulting assembly in a sandbox app domain as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094478/what-is-a-net-application-domain

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and things have considerably changed since it was asked. Now the Fable team have managed to run the F# compiler inside of a web-worker, removing the need to execute code on the server-side. This side-steps all of the security concerns around executing untrusted code.

- You can try out the REPL [here](https://fable.io/repl/).
- You can view the source-code [here](https://github.com/fable-compiler/repl).