# Is AppDomain equivalent to a Process for .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I have to call some badly written 3rd party COM components that have memory leaks and uses Single Threaded Apartment [STA] within a long running process.

I know separate process will be nice way to implement it and I can restart it occasionally from the long running process.

Can AppDomain be used instead? Is AppDomain thread a STA thread if marked appropiately? Does it have its own memory for COM objects? Is unloading the AppDomain is equivalent of killing the process?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An AppDomain does not provide the same degree of isolation as a process does. In fact if you're worried that the 3rd party component is not in good shape there's a risk, that it will take down your .NET application.

An AppDomain cannot be unloaded if unmanaged code is executing at the time of unload, so you may have a hard time controlling your 3rd party code in an AppDomain. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx

Even for managed code only, an AppDomain does not provide a robust sandbox solution. E.g. if the loaded code spawns any threads these will take down the entire process in case of unhandled exceptions. This question has a bit more info: [.NET - What's the best way to implement a "catch all exceptions handler"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219594/net-whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-catch-all-exceptions-handler).

As far as I am aware the best option for hosting code like that in a .NET application is to implement your own CLR host process like IIS and SQL Server does.

Answer (score 0):

An [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) (application domain), is an isolated environment where applications execute.

> They help provide isolation,
>   unloading, and security boundaries for
>   executing managed code.
>
> - Use application domains to isolate tasks that might bring down a process.
>     If the state of the AppDomain that's
>     executing a task becomes unstable, the
>     AppDomain can be unloaded without
>     affecting the process. This is
>     important when a process must run for
>     long periods without restarting. You
>     can also use application domains to
>     isolate tasks that should not share
>     data.
> - If an assembly is loaded into the default application domain, it cannot
>     be unloaded from memory while the
>     process is running. However, if you
>     open a second application domain to
>     load and execute the assembly, the
>     assembly is unloaded when that
>     application domain is unloaded. Use
>     this technique to minimize the working
>     set of long-running processes that
>     occasionally use large DLLs.
>
> Multiple application domains can run
>   in a single process; however, there is
>   not a one-to-one correlation between
>   application domains and threads.
>   Several threads can belong to a single
>   application domain, and while a given
>   thread is not confined to a single
>   application domain, at any given time,
>   a thread executes in a single
>   application domain.

SO Questions that might be of interest:

- [What is a .Net app domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094478/what-is-a-net-app-domain)
- [I don’t understand AppDomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622516/i-dont-understand-appdomains)

I won't profess to be an expert in the area of AppDomains, but I am fairly sure that a COM object leaking memory (i.e. unmanaged memory) will not be freed by unloading the AppDomain. Perhaps someone more familiar with this could comment.

As Brian pointed out, "... in the .NET Framework version 2.0 domain is not guaranteed to unload, because it might not be possible to terminate executing threads. "

Comment: I'm curious to see what the answer is as well. I don't have one to offer right now.