# what is appdomain in .NET

Tags: .net

Please let me know what is app domain in .NET

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/1253228/38206

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=VS.100%29.aspx what do you really want to know, because that web page is the explanation of what one is.

Answer (score 1):

It is an isolated region in which code runs inside of a process. One way to think of it is like a process sitting inside of your main process.

Each AppDomain exists within a process in total isolation, which allows you to run code safely with separate security, etc.

You can easily Google this to find out more.

Comment: I wouldn't call it total isolation. E.g. an unhandled exception will take down the process and any AppDomains in it.