# What is a .NET Application Domain?

Tags: .net, appdomain, applicationdomain

What is exactly is an Application Domain (AppDomain) and how is it different than a process or thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't understand Application Domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622516/i-dont-understand-application-domains)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx).

> Application domains provide a more secure and versatile unit of processing that the common language runtime can use to provide isolation between applications. You can run several application domains in a single process with the same level of isolation that would exist in separate processes, but without incurring the additional overhead of making cross-process calls or switching between processes. The ability to run multiple applications within a single process dramatically increases server scalability.

An AppDomain is basically an isolated execution environment for managed code.

Comment: +1 Think of it as a "lightweight process" and you'll usually be close enough.

Answer (score 2):

An [application domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx) is the "space" segments of code can run in.  It can be used for a couple of things such as creating a sandbox when loading assemblies that you don't fully trust.  It's different than a thread/process in that it houses the code that is being executed instead of actually being executed code.  In a broad sense you can think of any application as an application domain.